# Django template ajax call to api - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[object Object]'

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, api

Hi I'm trying to call to my `django api` with an ajax call from my `django template`

The API receive a POST request with the value of an id in the url

My api view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_favorite(request, property_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            favorite_property = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                login_user = request.user
                if not login_user.properties.filter(pk=property_id).exists():
                    login_user.properties.add(favorite_property)

                    return JsonResponse({'code':'200','data': favorite_property.id}, status=200)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'code':'404','errors': "Property already exists in favorite"}, status=404)

        except Property.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'code':'404','errors': "Property not found"}, status=404)
```

My html with the anchor link to ajax call:

```
<a id="mylink" href="javascript:onclickFunction('{{ property.id }}')">
     <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Add to favorite"></i>
</a>
```

And this is how i call to API in my django view to try and get response:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mylink').on('click', function (property_id) {
                property_id.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:9999/api/add_favorite/" + property_id.toString() + "/",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {{ refresh_token }}');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        alert(obj);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

When i try to press the link it return the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[object Object]'
>       web_1       | [24/Sep/2019 03:13:14] "POST /api/add_favorite/[object%20Object]/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17473

I tried to turn the property_id into a string seem like it still doesn't work, i don't know what else am i missing.I'm kind of a noob at jquery

Thank for reading my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed my script to :

```
$('#mylink').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                property_id = $(this).attr("value")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:9999/api/add_favorite/" + property_id + "/",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {{ refresh_token }}');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.code == 200) {
                            alert('ok');
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

and my html to :

```
<a id="mylink" href="javascript:onclickFunction()" value="{{ property.id }}">
      <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Add to favorite"></i>
</a>
```

and it worked now